# fill datatable from previous records

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

Good night guys, i have some data that i bind from database and show in a listview depending on a combobox with months. If i select January i bind from database and he suffers some modifications that i required, so far so good, what i want is when i select the next month that he fills the datatable with the new order and not from database with the default values.

for example on January i bind to day 1 - "someData" and day 2 - "SomeOtherData" and so on, but in the middle of the month i trade the order of them, ex: day 25 - "someOtherData" and day 26 - "someData". On the next month i want that in Day 1 he puts "someOtherData" and Day 2 - "someData".

Summing up if i select January he bind from database, if i select other month i want that he bind from datatable.

Thank you, best regards

---

Imagine i have 3 datatable, dtGraduado, dtWeek and dtWeekend:

dtGraduado has a for with datetime showing:

Date | Name | KindOfDay

01Jan17  -    --Sunday

02Jan17  -    --Monday

03Jan17  -    --Tuesday

04Jan17  -    --Wednesday

05Jan17  -    --Thursday

...         ...

31Jan17   -   C --Tuesday

on dtWeekend i bind data acoording to last date (16/Dec/16) and populate on dtGraduado (the first row in database is "C") only on weekends.
on dtWeek i bind data acoording to last date (17/Dec/16) and populate on dtGraduado (the first row in database is also "C") only on day of the week.

Date | Name | KindOfDay

01Jan17  -   C --Sunday

02Jan17  -   C --Monday

03Jan17  -   A --Tuesday

04Jan17  -   F --Wednesday

05Jan17  -   B --Thursday

...         ...

31Jan17   -   C --Tuesday

Next in .cs i compare rows, seeing that there are 2 "C"'s next to each other, and i trade the position of them with the next available name, and it stay like this:

Date | Name | KindOfDay

01Jan17  -   C --Sunday

02Jan17  -   **A** --Monday

03Jan17  -   **C** --Tuesday

04Jan17  -   F --Wednesday

05Jan17  -   B --Thursday

...         ...

31Jan17   -   C --Tuesday

and he save in dtWeek and dtWeekend the corresponding dates (not on database, because i wanted to be like that). Ohh this all code is on a cbCurrentMonth_SelectionChanged, but the problem is when i choose February, he binds again from database and i wanted that he binds form dtWeek and dtWeekend that has been previously saved in January month.

Tell me if you dont understand anything please, thanks

Comment: So what you want is, when user selects a month from combobox, orders of that month should be retrieved from the database and displayed in the listview. Right ?

Comment: nop lol i pass the data from the database to a datatable called dtWeekend, during the "for daysinMonth" the data has been changed. in the second month i want to bind data from the datatable dtWeekend that as been modified

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote for this and tell what is not working properly in the code?

Comment: i update the message